# PowerShell: Get 2 strings into a hashtable and out to .csv

Tags: csv, powershell

PowerShell newbie here,

I need to:

1. Get text files in recursive local directories that have a common string, **students.txt** in them.
2. Get another string, **gc.student="*name*,*name*"** in the resulting file set from #1 and get the *name*(s).
3. Put the filename from #1, and just the *name*,*name* from #2 (not **gc.student="")** into a hashtable where the filename is paired with its corresponding *name*,*name*.
4. Output the hashtable to an Excel spreadsheet with 2 columns: **File** and **Name**.

I've figured out, having searched and learned here and elsewhere, how to output #1 to the screen, but not how to put it into a hashtable with #2:

```
$documentsfolder = "C:\records\"
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $documentsfolder -recurse | Select String -pattern "students.txt" ) {$file}
```

I'm thinking to get *name* in #2 I'll need to use a RegEx since there might only be 1 *name* sometimes.
And for the output to Excel, this: `| Export-Csv -NoType output.csv`

Any help moving me on is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you started. The explanations are in the code comments.

```
# base directory
$documentsfolder = 'C:\records\'

# get files with names ending with students.txt
$files = Get-ChildItem $documentsfolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*students.txt"}

# process each of the files
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $fileContents = Get-Content $file
    $fileName = $file.Name

    #series of matches to clean up different parts of the content
    #first find the gc.... pattern
    $fileContents = ($fileContents | Select-String -Pattern 'gc.student=".*"').Matches.Value
    # then select the string with double quotes
    $fileContents = ($fileContents | Select-String '".*"').Matches.Value
    # then remove the leading and trailing double quotes
    $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '^"','' -replace '"$',''

    # drop the objects to the pipeline so that you can pipe it to export-csv
    # I am creating custom objects so that your CSV headers will nave nice column names
    Write-Output [pscustomobject]@{file=$fileName;name=$fileContents}
} | Export-Csv -NoType output.csv
```